# x8086 Assembly, pushing 0.0001 onto stack becomes 9.99999.. instead of 0.0001

Tags: assembly, floating-point, floating-point-conversion, x87

I am trying to implement newtons algorithm for square roots. I have included the complete C program so you can see what i am trying to do. I am trying to write the C program included below in assembly. Right now i am just trying to correctly write the while loop. I am pushing 0.0001 onto the stack with the command `fld accuracy`. Below is the screenshot of my registers. ST0 should be 0.0001, but instead it is 9.999. How do i correct this value so that i can do a compare with 0.0001 instead of 9.999..? [image: xcv]

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096                 
.data
    PUBLIC _newton
upper REAL4 9.0
accuracy REAL4 0.00001
lower REAL4 1.0
.code

_newton  PROC

        finit   ;initialize fpu
        fld upper
        fld lower
        fsub
        fld accuracy
        fcom
        ;if less than call code for the rest of the algorithm.
        mov eax, 0
        ret

_newton ENDP
END
```

C version of the algorithm i am implementing:

```
double sqrtX (double x)
{
    const double ACCURACY=0.00001;
    double lower, upper, guess;
    double number;

    number = x;
    lower = 1;
    upper = number;

    while ((upper-lower) > ACCURACY)
    {
        guess = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if((guess * guess) > number)
        {
            upper = guess;
        }
        else
        {
            lower = guess;
        }
    }
    return (lower + upper)/2;
}
```

Comment: When loading onto the FPU stack .00001 can't be represented exactly. It was stored as 9.999999999....e-0006. which is .0000099999999999... I've used `...` to denote the rest of the digits as I wasn't going to reproduce them here (too lazy).

Comment: @Michael Petch  Ok, well that's strange, because .0000099999999999 is just 9.99999... times bigger than .00001. I'm definitely not used to thinking in terms of assembly.

Comment: This isn't about assembly., I think you may have to read about normalizing numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_number . You are missing the fact that it ends with `e-0006` . It is in scientific notation.

Comment: @Some_Dude if you will use in the debugger the watch/evaluate windows, you can probably add some formatting modifiers to avoid scientific notation (for the price of rounding), if this is MS visual studio, then you may have some chance (can't recall if it had such modifier, but it has some others for sure, so there's chance), but in some debuggers you are out of luck and you have to read the value correctly in the format provided by debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's 9.99...**e-6** which is the closest representable FP value to 0.00001.

You missed the exponent part of the scientific notation, and that `0.00001` is not exactly representable in binary floating point.

Comment: So they are equal? I would get the same result if i performed arithmetic operations on that number?

Comment: Your question says you want 0.0001 , which is still a 100x larger that ST0's approximate value

Comment: @Some_Dude: No, they're not equal, but what you got is the correctly-rounded result of converting `0.00001` to single-precision `float` / REAL4 / IEEE binary32. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Thanks for the edit @peter cordes. (I became active very recently and am still learning :) )

Comment: cheers, welcome to SO :).  I like how on SO we can just edit answers to make them better instead of complaining in comments.  It works really well for cases like this where it's the right answer but needs more detail.

Comment: @Some_Dude here is the common (fast) floating point of computer math explained: http://floating-point-gui.de/ ... there are still libraries which calculate with non-native floating point values encoded in different way (for example as strings), working "accurately" in decimals, but those calculations are then much slower, as even simple addition involves tens/hundreds of instructions instead of single `fadd`, for example in our mobile banking apps we are using Java class "BigDecimal" for monetary amounts, as native `float` would introduce rounding inaccuracy (we can afford "slow" code there).